# How to transform a curl request in an axios request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, curl, react-native

i have HTTP Curl Request but i dont know how to tranform it to an axios request.

**CURL**

```
curl -H 'User-Agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 6.0.1; SM-G900F Build/MMB29M)' -H 'Content-Type: application/json;arset=UTF-8' -H 'Host: reiseauskunft.bahn.de' --data-binary '{"auth":{"aid":"n91dB8Z77MLdoR0K","type":"AID"},"client":{"id":"DB","name":"DB Navigator","os":"Android 6.0.1","res":"1080x1920","type":"AND","ua":"Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 6.0.1; SM-G900F Build/MMB29M)","v":18040000},"ext":"DB.R18.04.a","formatted":false,"svcReqL":[{"cfg":{"polyEnc":"GPA","rtMode":"HYBRID"},"meth":"TripSearch","req":{"outDate":"20180531","outTime":"204603","arrLocL":[{"crd":{"x":9684169,"y":50554794},"extId":"8000115","lid":"A=1@O=Fulda@X=9683980@Y=50554722@U=80@L=008000115@B=1@p=1525745008@","name":"Fulda","type":"S"}],"depLocL":[{"crd":{"x":13386988,"y":52520501},"extId":"8096003","lid":"A=1@O=BERLIN@X=13386988@Y=52520501@U=80@L=008096003@B=1@p=1526433964@","name":"BERLIN","type":"S"}],"getPasslist":true,"getPolyline":true,"jnyFltrL":[{"mode":"BIT","type":"PROD","value":"11111111111111"}],"trfReq":{"cType":"PK","jnyCl":2,"tvlrProf":[{"type":"E"}]}}}],"ver":"1.15"}' --compressed 'https://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/mgate.exe?checksum=6d6fa2fac99949c118a40baf411875a0'
```

**AXIOS**

```
   axios(
    { 
    method: 'POST', 
    url: 'https://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/mgate.exe?checksum=6d6fa2fac99949c118a40baf411875a0', 
    headers:  {
        'User-Agent': 'Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 6.0.1; SM-G900F Build/MMB29M)',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        'Host': 'reiseauskunft.bahn.de'
    }, 
    data:  {"auth":{"aid":"n91dB8Z77MLdoR0K","type":"AID"},"client":{"id":"DB","name":"DB Navigator","os":"Android 6.0.1","res":"1080x1920","type":"AND","ua":"Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 6.0.1; SM-G900F Build/MMB29M)","v":18040000},"ext":"DB.R18.04.a","formatted":false,"svcReqL":[{"cfg":{"polyEnc":"GPA","rtMode":"HYBRID"},"meth":"TripSearch","req":{"outDate":"20180531","outTime":"204603","arrLocL":[{"crd":{"x":9684169,"y":50554794},"extId":"8000115","lid":"A=1@O=Fulda@X=9683980@Y=50554722@U=80@L=008000115@B=1@p=1525745008@","name":"Fulda","type":"S"}],"depLocL":[{"crd":{"x":13386988,"y":52520501},"extId":"8096003","lid":"A=1@O=BERLIN@X=13386988@Y=52520501@U=80@L=008096003@B=1@p=1526433964@","name":"BERLIN","type":"S"}],"getPasslist":true,"getPolyline":true,"jnyFltrL":[{"mode":"BIT","type":"PROD","value":"11111111111111"}],"trfReq":{"cType":"PK","jnyCl":2,"tvlrProf":[{"type":"E"}]}}}],"ver":"1.15"}
}).then(response){
    console.log('===========response=========================');
    console.log(response);
    console.log('====================================');
}
```

It does not work. Somebody knows why? I get as an response an empty array

Comment: the curl command you provided gave me a non empty result from the server

Comment: yes for me, too but the axios request give me an empty array

Comment: how do you check the result? can you give use more example code how you call the request exactly

Comment: Shouldn't you be sending the request data via the `data` property as a JS object?

Comment: same thing when I change body to data

Comment: Are you sending it as a string, or a JavaScript object?

Comment: string like in my post

Comment: how do you check the response? pls show some code

Comment: i have edited it. response is empty

Comment: I get a 500 response when sending a request to that URL.

Comment: problem was that in then must be a function. .then((response) =>{...})